# Custom function which behaves like `Evaluate`

Tags: evaluation, hold, symbols

## Question

Is there a way to define a function which evaluates itself regardless of `HoldAll`, `HoldFirst`, ... ?

## Background

I'm writing a function which makes it easier to document other functions using `::usage`, `SyntaxInformation` and code completion. I also use code generation and I want to document the generated code.

Therefore I need to define new symbols with a usage message and remove them like this:

```
(* I already get an error message here since `Evaluate` wants to evaluate
  `Symbol[name]` but `name` is not a string yet *)
NewSymbol[name_String] := Evaluate[Symbol[name]];

Remove[NewSymbol["test"]] (* DOES NOT WORK *)
NewSymbol["test"]::usage = "This is a test"; (* DOES NOT WORK *)


(* In order to make it work I have to use an additional `Evaluate`*)

(* The same is true if I want to use `Remove` *)
Remove[Evaluate[NewSymbol["test"]]]

Evaluate[NewSymbol["test"]]::usage = "This is a test";
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What goal is it intended to serve? With that info, answers might be more helpful.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Thank you for your comment. Is the intention clear now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stay away from [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) altogether and use [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to inject into functions that hold their arguments:

```
createSymbolAndSetUsage[sym_String, usage_String] := With[
    {symbol = Symbol @ sym},
    symbol::usage = usage;
    symbol
]

createSymbolAndSetUsage["Foo", "Foo does what it does"]
(* Foo *)
```

[image]